# Wix , cant find last node , why?

Tags: xpath, wix

Why this won't work ?
I want to select the last item  Items  (where the cursor is at)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
/RadDocking/DocumentHost/RadsplitContainer/Items/RadPaneGroup[last()]
```

Hope it will help you :)